# XSLT-1.0: Convert comma-separated values to element values

Tags: xml, xslt, converters, tokenize

I am attempting to take an XML file and convert it with XSLT.
The XML I am trying to convert looks like this:

```
<root>
  <TAG>10, 1, 3, 123, 4001, 34, 200, 105, 54, 0, 0, 0</TAG>
</root>
```

When I run the conversion, I would like the result to appear like this:

```
<Field1>10</Field1>
<Field2>1</Field2>
...
<Field12>0</Field12>
```

However, my XSLT file is not working like designed.
Whenever I run the converter, I get back this as a response:

```
<Field_1>
  <TAG>10, 1, 3, 123, 4001, 34, 200, 105, 54, 0, 0, 0</TAG>
</Field_1>
```

Here is my XSLT file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" version="1.0">
<xsl:strip-space elements = "*"/>
<xsl:output method = "xml" indent = "yes"/>

<xsl:template match = "@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:call-template name="listItem">
        <xsl:with-param name="tag" select="TAG"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="listItem">
    <xsl:param name="features"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($features, ',')">
            <xsl:element name="Field_{position()}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($features, ','))"/>
                <xsl:variable name="nextValue" select="substring-after($features, ',')"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:if test="normalize-space($nextValue)">
                <xsl:call-template name="listItem">
                    <xsl:with-param name="features" select="$nextValue"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="Field_{position()}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$features"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to get my XSLT file to convert my XML into the desired result?
Please and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this XSLT.
It is XSLT version 1.0 and uses recursion via a named `<xsl:template>` called `field` to delimit the comma-separated values and encapsulate each of the values in `<Field>` elements. The element's name is generated of the static string `Field` plus a recursively passed variable named `cnt`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" />

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
      <xsl:call-template name="field">
        <xsl:with-param name="cnt" select="1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="txt" select="concat(TAG/text(),',')" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="field">
    <xsl:param name="cnt" />
    <xsl:param name="txt" />
    <xsl:element name="{concat('Field',$cnt)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before($txt,','))"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space(substring-after($txt,',')) != ''">
      <xsl:call-template name="field">
        <xsl:with-param name="cnt" select="$cnt + 1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="txt" select="substring-after($txt,',')" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result - as desired - is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <Field1>10</Field1>
    <Field2>1</Field2>
    <Field3>3</Field3>
    <Field4>123</Field4>
    <Field5>4001</Field5>
    <Field6>34</Field6>
    <Field7>200</Field7>
    <Field8>105</Field8>
    <Field9>54</Field9>
    <Field10>0</Field10>
    <Field11>0</Field11>
    <Field12>0</Field12>
</root>
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly.